# Is there a way to filter results with specific extension in Google (or any browser)?

Tags: search, filter, browser, formatting, format

> Is there a way to filter results with specific extension in Google (or
> any browser)?

There are several ways to filter results, such as `site:`, `-`, `+` or `""`.

So, can I somehow get websites that has a specific extension by doing something like this?

**P.S** I know, it's kind of a general question that isn't directly related to programming, but I don't know where else to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension, [Google Search Filter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-filter/eidhkmnbiahhgbgpjpiimdogfidfikgf?hl=en)

Please comment below if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: Thanks for this! I played around with it and it seems efficient.

Comment: @LercDsgn https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Why did you link that? edit: I found out why, there is something that says:
*Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say* *"Thank you"*... So, this means that.. I should delete my comment?